# Exponentiation with a random variable

Tags: probability

My professor has given us this problem, but I'm not familiar with the notation:

$A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent (random variables). $P(A) = P(B) = 0.5$, $P(C) = 0.2$. Find $P(A \cup B^c \cup C)$

His published solution begins with $P(A \cup B^c \cup C) = 1 - P((A \cup B^c \cup C)^c)$. This doesn't help me very much, since I can't even find out a name for this notation in order to look up how to deal with or use it. It's not in the textbook assigned for the class (in fact, it's part of an "optional lecture series" that he has given towards the end of the semester).

What meaning does exponentiation of a random variable to a random variable have, if that is even what it's called?

Comment: The question is, what is $P(A)$ when $A$ is random variable? 

This all makes sense if $A$ is an _event_ instead of random variable -- then $A^c$ is just an opposite event, that is, $\Omega - A$.

Comment: It's not an exponential, it means B complement. As in, if $B \subset X$ then $B^c$ is the set $X$ exclude $B$.

Comment: How embarrassing. Usually he uses $\bar{X}$ for X compliment. This sudden change in notation mixed with the fact that he used $C$ later left me very confused, and now that I posted this question, quite embarrassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exponentiation; it appears to be set notation.

It could mean a number of things, each with similar but different meanings, depending on what your $P$ represents.

P could represent the distribution of some random variable $X$. A random variable is just a (measurable) function that takes a *set of outcomes* (we call this an '*event*') to a *real number* (or multiple real numbers, or some other measurable space). If $P$ represents the distribution of a random variable, then $A$ is some set in the range of $X$, and $P(A)$ is shorthand for: $P(\{\text{all the events `}\omega \text{' where }X(\omega)\in A\})$

On the other hand, $P$ could represent the probability measure for your set of events. 
Under this assumption, $A, B, C$ represent events. $P(A)=k$, for some event $A$ and some number $k$ from $0$ to $1$ indicates 'the probability of anything in the set $A$ happening is $k$'

In either case, your $A,B,C$ represent sets.